# How to include filter in mat select nested values using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material with nested dropdowns. The dropdown values nested with parent and child basis.

I'm facing two issues.

1. Auto suggestion is not working. If I type parent name or its associated child name, have to filter and show the particular parent view with expand mode.
2. If i expand first parent and trying to expand the second parent,  the first parent view should close automatically while expanding the second one.

Please find the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-9fpccz which i am using to do the sample.

**Anyone help will be appreciated!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st requirement `mat-select` won't work. You have to use `mat-autocomplete`.

Please find my solution here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-flcevo

Comment: thanks for your response. For me, the JSON will be dynamic which i get via rest service call.

Comment: Thats not an issue. You can get json from your response then after initialize valueChange event.

Comment: And please accept and upvote my answer if this work fine for you.

Comment: Auto suggestion is not working properly. First time i typed some values which not available in the list. The next time i typed value which available in list like letter "A", I am getting error as "ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'letter' of undefined" and If I create some extra object in the current json , the filter is not working for that as expected. Can you help me to resolve the issue? thanks

Comment: try now with same stackblitz undefined error will be gone. And If you want to add extra objects then you should follow the same structure then it will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. 1) I have typed letter "D"  in input box & its get filtered. But, if i select all or select any one value, the selected values is not get bind in input box. 2) And I have created new object in json like letter "E" and "F". The filter is not working for the new one.

Comment: 1. we can't bind input box if you want selected values you can get that from stateRecord. 2. Please attach E and F object will check why its not working.

Comment: but my requirement is to show the selected values in input field

Comment: filter won't work properly if you display it on input.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-ce3jdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts  check for the second one

Comment: you are adding wrong json. here E the names should be start with E and under F names should be start with F.

Comment: No.Parent name and child name may differ. Its not like should start with its first name

Comment: Check your question please.

Comment: According to your question if my answer is correct please accept my answer and upvote. And for your new requirement please create separate question but before that understand this answer and try something by your self first. In stackoverflow someone can help you to solve you issue it's not means that your whole task can somebody do entirely.  You have to give your efforts first. Hope you understand my point. And don't take it personal.

Comment: Its not like, I doesn't try from my end. I have tried & I didn't get solution. so that I have raised question here. And I work with your code & modified it based on my requirement. Still i faced issue. Its quiet urgent too. That's the reason for my comments. Anyway thanks for your complements